# Binding WPF PopupColorEdit to a Custom List

Tags: wpf

I'm a WPF's beginner developer, how can I do binding from List or ObserverCollection to PopupColorEdit.

thanks

Comment: What is PopUpColorEdit ??? A usercontrol ???

Comment: yes, it is ... I pulled it from the toolBox

Comment: I dont see it in my toolbox... is it 3rd party ???

Comment: I bvelieve u sre using PopUpColor Edit from devexpress....

Comment: maybe, it looks like this in xaml file, <dxe:PopUpColorEdit ...

Comment: yes, it is a devexpress control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the documentation it appears that it has a Palettes property which is a collection of CustomPalette objects. CustomPalettes can be instantiated by giving a name and providing a List of Colors. Like so:

```
popupColorEdit1.Palettes.Add( 
    new CustomPalette("Custom RGB Colors", new List<Color>() {
                    Color.FromRgb(150, 18, 30),
                    Color.FromRgb(20, 40, 20),
                    Color.FromRgb(88, 73, 29) }));
```

So you'd have a collection of CustomPalettes in your viewmodel (or code behind) and bind either from XAML or programatically.

Does that help?